# Which python package solver?

Tags: numpy, scipy, solver

If I have a `mesh` of 3D data of the x-coord, y-coord, and the function value `f` at x,y: `XX`, `YY`, `f(XX, YY)`, and I want to discover all the `linear relations`, n,m such that:

`nf(XX, YY) - mf(XX, YY)  ~ 0` [constraint n,m are integers]

which python package would I use?

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be `contour`. However, `contour` appears to be tightly tied to the local graphics of the python environment, in particular `matplotlib.pyplot`